# How come Booktabs doesn't work in some cases?

Tags: xetex, booktabs

I'm using xtable (R package) for generating a simple table. It works fine and I would like to color some specific lines so I have added the relevant packages:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
```

In case I run the Rnw file **directly** The code works well and does the job :) with the row's colors.
**BUT** if I run the Shiny app (with XeLaTeX) which executes the same Rnw file via knit, the colors surprisingly vanishes with no notice. I'm not transferring any data from the Shiny app to the Rnw file, the exact Rnw code remained the same but **fails with the colors**, seems to me very strange.

I have compared the contents of the **generated tex** in both cases and those files are the same.

What am I missing? Can someone please shed some light on the mystery? :)

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\setmonofont{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\frenchspacing
\makeatother
\usepackage{xunicode} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

<<testing-xtable3,results='asis',echo=FALSE,cache=FALSE>>=

library(xtable)

# Just fake data in the dataframe
my_data <- data.frame(call_date = c("2014-10-05", "2014-10-05","2014-10-05"),
            days_of_week = c("item 2", "B","F"),
            time = c("07:28:52", "07:28:52","07:28:52"),
            duration = c("item 4", "D","H"),
            cost_per_minute = c("item 4", "D","H"),
            dst = c("90545614735", "90545614735","90545614735"))

df_xtable <- xtable(x=my_data,
                    caption="A table",
                    label="my_data")

# align should hold ( ncol(df) + 1 ), don't forget the extra column

align(df_xtable) <- "ccccccX"                  # with vertical lines: "|l|l|X|X|l|X|X|"
                                               # l stands for Left
                                               # r stands for Right
                                               # c stands for Center

rows_gray <- c(0,2)
my_col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rows_gray))

print(
  df_xtable,
  include.rownames = FALSE,
  table.placement = "h",
  latex.environments = "center",                 # Center the table to the page
  tabular.environment = "tabularx",             # tables whose overall width is fixed.
  width = "\\textwidth",
  booktabs = TRUE,
  add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rows_gray), command = my_col)
  )
@
\end{document}
```

Thank you all,

Gil

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please add the code to your question as text, then select it all and click the button that looks like `{}` to properly format and display it as code.

Comment: Thank you Alenanno, I have added my code here as you suggested.

Comment: Off-topic: don't load `colortbl` and `xcolor` separately. Instead, run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. See Table 1 of the user guide of the `xcolor` package for more information.

Comment: What is Shiny app? Maybe I'm just dumb, but I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: As the code runs when compiled directly, I suspect that this problem is more to do with the Shiny server than to do with TeX. If so then this is should be closed as "off-topic'" because it does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems.

Comment: I just have found out the colors appearance depends on the pdf viewer, on FoxitReader both on Linux and Windows there is no color at all. BUT on evince the colors appears. so I guess it's not a tex problem! anyway thank you all for trying to assist me :)